# Dictionary containing Functions and Optional parameter

Tags: c#, function, dictionary, .net-core, parameters

I have a dictionary setup with the following:

```
    private Dictionary<string, Promotion> availablePromotions = new Dictionary<string, Promotion>()
    {
        { "BestHorseRacingFreeBetSidebarOffers", Client.GetHorseRacingSignUpOffersSidebarWidget() },
        { "BestHorseRacingBettingSidebarOffers", Client.GetHorseRacingBettingOffersSidebarWidget() },
        { "BestHorseRacingBettingOffers", Client.GetBestHorseRacingBettingOffersWidget() },
        { "BestHorseRacingFreeBetOffers", Client.GetBestHorseRacingSignUpOffersWidget()  },
        { "BestFootballBettingOffers", Client.GetBestFootballBettingOffersWidget() },
        { "TopFootballBettingOffer", Client.GetFootballBettingOfferWidget() },
        { "BestFootballFreeBetOffers", Client.GetBestFootballSignUpOffersWidget() },
        { "TopFootballFreeBetOffer", Client.GetTopFootballSignUpOfferWidget() },
        { "TopHorseRacingFreeBetOffer", Client.GetTopHorseRacingSignUpOfferWidget() },
        { "TopHorseRacingBettingOffer", Client.GetTopHorseRacingBettingOfferWidget() }
    };
```

And I have a view component Invoke function that applies 'vm' to the function within the dictionary based on the 'promotionType':

```
  public IViewComponentResult Invoke(string promotionType, CompanyEnum? companyId)
    {
        Promotion vm;

        if(promotionType == "TopFreeBetOffer")
        {
            vm = Client.GetTopBookmakerSpecificSignUpOfferWidget((CompanyEnum)companyId);
        }
        else if (promotionType == "BestFreeBetOffers")
        {
            vm = Client.GetBestBookmakerSpecificSignUpOffersWidget((CompanyEnum)companyId);
        }
        else if (promotionType == "TopBettingOffer")
        {
            vm = Client.GetTopBookmakerSpecificBettingOfferWidget((CompanyEnum)companyId);
        }
        else if (promotionType == "BestBettingOffers")
        {
            vm = Client.GetBestBookmakerSpecificBettingOffersWidget((CompanyEnum)companyId);
        }
        else
        {
            vm = availablePromotions[promotionType];
        }

        return View(vm);
    }
```

As you can see I have a few functions that take a parameter called 'companyId'.

How do I make it so I can add the functions with the parameter to my dictionary instead of using the if statements?

Comment: Utilize the conditional to polymorphism approach. Basically take your conditional variables and create classes for them. There are different behavioral patterns available depending on your needs. A simple factory pattern will work or even something like the chain of responsibility pattern. Using objects instead of logic will greatly reduce your conditional statements: https://www.dofactory.com/net/design-patterns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store the delegates in the dictionary, with the methods that don't need the parameter you can just ignore it. On this way you can store them all in it:

```
private Dictionary<string, Func<CompanyEnum?, Promotion>> availablePromotions = new Dictionary<string, Func<CompanyEnum?, Promotion>>()
{
    { "BestHorseRacingFreeBetSidebarOffers", companyId => Client.GetHorseRacingSignUpOffersSidebarWidget() },
    { "BestHorseRacingBettingSidebarOffers", companyId => Client.GetHorseRacingBettingOffersSidebarWidget() },
    { "TopFreeBetOffer", companyId => Client.GetTopBookmakerSpecificSignUpOfferWidget(companyId) },
    { "BestFreeBetOffers", companyId => Client.GetBestBookmakerSpecificSignUpOffersWidget(companyId) },
    // ...
};
```

Your `Invoke` method would become concise(maybe use`TryGetValue`):

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke(string promotionType, CompanyEnum? companyId)
{
    Promotion vm = availablePromotions[promotionType](companyId);
    return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: Probably you will have to call the nullable enum with `.Value` as in `{ "TopFreeBetOffer", c => Client.GetTopBookmakerSpecificSignUpOfferWidget(c.Value) },`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you guys.